# JavaScript native form abilities

Tags: javascript

Say I have form with 2 inputs (email and password) that the user submits. onSubmit I process the form with a fetch call, catch the errors and need to display it back to the user. ie. an error such as "The email address you provided does not exist". So basically a typical login form. I'd like to display this message to the user via the native form warning displays.

I see there's a way to set the inputs custom message with *setCustomValidity* but I'm not sure how to display the message again once I've determined there's an error.

After some research I've determined that I have to apparently resubmit the form to display the custom error. Other sites claim that I can do it directly. It's rather confusing.

So the question is how can I set then instantly display a custom input error to take advantage of native form validation?

Comment: Use `reportValidity()` to make it show the message.

Comment: On the element or the form? I tried that...no worky!

Comment: On the form, after calling `setCustomValidity()` on the input.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/20dqae5x/

Comment: Something else must be wrong cause it's not displaying the native error field. Sigh. Thanks!

Comment: Post your code and we can try to help

Comment: All good. It was quite annoying, it seems like the form was receiving the setCustomValidity but I had to use setTimeout or queueMicrotask to trigger it

Comment: I didn't need to do that in my jsfiddle. I'm not sure why you did.

Comment: Yeah I don't understand either tbh. But it works now